# D3 arcTween - Updating transitions for multiple pie charts

Tags: d3.js

I've tried to create a set of d3 pie charts that draw when a json request is returned.

I can get the labels and background paths to work but I am unable to get the foreground paths to draw. I only encounter this problem when I try to create multiple pie charts.

An example of my current progress is provided here:
http://jsbin.com/wubohidefo/edit?html,js,output

Any help you can provide to get the foreground paths working or explain what is causing this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return `arc(d)` in `arcTween`:

```
function arcTween(transition, newAngle) {
    transition.attrTween("name", function(d) {

        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);
        return function(t) {
            d.endAngle = interpolate(t);
            text.text(((d.endAngle/τ)*10).toFixed(1));
            return arc(d);
        };
    }); 
}
```

You should instead be setting `foreground.attr("d", arc)`:

```
function arcTween(transition, newAngle) {
    transition.attrTween("name", function(d) {

        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(d.endAngle, newAngle);
        return function(t) {
            d.endAngle = interpolate(t);                
            text.text(((d.endAngle/τ)*10).toFixed(1));
            foreground.attr("d", arc);
        };
    }); 
}
```

Comment: MrHen, (hopefully you're still able to receive this) when the data is filtered and the function is called again to update the charts how would I get it to draw from its last position instead of drawing from 0? For example, if a chart is at 30 at the new value is 70, how do you get it to only move the foreground from 30 up to 70 not 0 to 70?

Comment: `foreground = svg.append("path").datum({endAngle: 0 * τ})` will need to be set to the starting angle. If you change it to `0.5 * τ`, then all arcs will start at the halfway point.